# Check if explode value count is greater than 0

Tags: php

I am retrieving some data from a table in mysql. The values are stored with a | separater
Example:
`test 1|test 2|test 4` and so on..
Everything works great except when there are blank entries in the column. I am using the following code.

```php
$groups = explode('|', $row['groups']);
if(count($groups) >0) 
{
   echo 'There are values';

}else{ 
   echo 'No values';
}
```

The problem I have is this returns 'There are values' even if the column is empty.
Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the string contains a pipe but no values?

Comment: [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get string(0) "" when I do a var_dump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)**

> If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE.
>   **If delimiter contains a value that is not contained in string and a negative limit is used, then an empty array will be returned,
>   otherwise an array containing string will be returned**

```
<?php
$g = "";
$e = explode('|',$g, -1) ;
if ($e) print "yes 1"; else print "Non 1";

$g = "";
$e = explode('|',$g, 1) ;
if ($e) print "yes 2"; else print "Non 2";

?>

Non 1
yes 2
```

The issue is that your returned array contains a single element that is empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Using both [`explode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) you can narrow down the options to **valid** tokens:

```
function count_tokens($field)
{
  $tokens = array_filter(explode('|',$field),create_function('$a','return !empty($a);'));
  return sizeof($tokens);
}
```

[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/2ITz9)

```
           = 0 tokens  
Foo        = 1 tokens  
Foo|Bar    = 2 tokens  
|          = 0 tokens  
||         = 0 tokens  
Foo||Bar   = 2 tokens  
Foo|Bar|   = 2 tokens  
|Foo|Bar   = 2 tokens
```

Comment: +1! nice. What about: array_filter(explode('|',$var),"strlen");   ?

Comment: @johntully, take in consideration this answer. May be better that mine. If is the case, check this one as solution.

Comment: @danihp: Indeed, was just giving author an additional method of filtering. I wasn't sure if existence was the only stipulation--this way the OP can change it to filter based on his/her own metrics.